# Как оптимизировать навешивание обработчиков на 1000 блоков?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, оптимизация

Вот говорят на собеседовании:

> Представь у тебя 1000 блоков и тебе нужно обработчик на каждый навесить. Как бы ты это оптимизировал ?

Comment: 1000 блоков и все разные? Дать им всем один класс: `$(".class").click(function(){...});` Все под одним родителем? `$(roditel).on("click", ".class", function(){...})`.

Answer (score 3):

Добавляешь всем общий класс (или что угодно, что можно использовать в css-селекторе). Потом на ближайшем общем родителе (или на `body`) подписываешься на всплытие клика по соответствующим элементам.

```js
$("body").on('click', "p", function (e) {
  console.log(this.outerHTML + "\n" + e.target.outerHTML)
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>123 <span>span <em>em</em></span></p>
<p>456 <span>span <em>em</em></span></p>
<p>789 <span>span <em>em</em></span></p>
```